# Surround Audio Channels Spatial Distribution

Tags: sound

I use Ubuntu-Studio 18.04.2 LTS (64 bit Linux) in a MSI H61M-P31W8 (MS-7788) motherboard desktop computer, with an internal Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset family (snd_hda_intel) surround audio card.

I use an external Behringer Xenix 1204USB audio mixer to "transport" the audio in and out the computer via one of the USB ports.

Everything is working so fine, when the audio is Stereo only. But, when I play some surround audio in the PC, I lost the sounds from the surround audio channels (left side and rear, right side and rear, LFE) in the final stereo audio amplifier.

Is there some way to change the spatial distribution of those channels (mixdown) in a way I get them all INSIDE the "normal" stereo channels (left and right)? ???